# sumif doesn't run "not" when cell is blank

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice

I'm trying to summarize cells where field is not a given value. This works in Google Docs and MS Office, but in LibreOffice and OpenOffice it only summarizes when the call has a value.

If E7 (see attached image) had a value of `foo`, LibreOffice would summarize that row. Why doesn't it run on blank fields as Google Docs does?

```
=SUMIF(E7:E1000, "<>Foobar", B7:B1000)
```

[image]

What do I need to do to have it work in LibreOffice as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SUMPRODUCT](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Conditional_Counting_and_Summation#SUMPRODUCT) instead.  It is more powerful than SUMIF, although it is less intuitive.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(E7:E1000<>"Foobar", B7:B1000)
```

See https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=49026 for a discussion.